# Is defineProperty method inherited from Object?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, defineproperty

If all objects inherit from Object then why can't i use the defineProperty method of Object in this way?

```
var car = {name:"honda"}

car.defineProperty(car, "jow", {value:"jow"})

alert(car.jow)
```

Thx for your insight,

Answer (score 1):

Because defineProperty is not a property of Object's prototype, it is a property of Object itself.

So to use it, do this: (from documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```
var o = {}; // Creates a new object

// Example of an object property added with defineProperty with a data property descriptor
Object.defineProperty(o, "a", {value : 37,
                               writable : true,
                               enumerable : true,
                               configurable : true});
// 'a' property exists in the o object and its value is 37
```

Also, here's a good link explaining protos and inheritance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff852808.aspx